# Given a characteristic polynomial of A how to know if B is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Suppose that I have a matrix A with the following characteristic polynomial

P$_A$(x)=(x-4)$^2$(x-1)$^3$(x-5)

How can I tell if the following matrix B is invertible?

B=-5A$^2$+10A-5I

I tried to multiply the components of P(x) but i didnt find anything common between the two equations.

I know that P$_A$(x) is also $x^6-16x^5+98x^4-288x^3+421x^2-296x+80
$ but I guess it doesnt help much.

thank you.

Comment: What happens if you put x=0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, $B$ is not invertible, because of 0 being one of its eigenvalues.

1 is an eigenvalue of $A$, let $x$ be corresponded eigenvector.
$Bx = -5A^2x+10Ax-5x=0x$

Answer (score 1):

- A matrix $A$ is invertible if, and only if $\det(A) \neq 0$
- But $\det(A)$ is exactly the product of $A$`s eigenvalues.
- Now, $A$'s eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristical polynomial.

So, from these three premises it's easy to conclude that $A$ is invertible if, and only if, $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. The problem is, this answers the question in the title, which is different than the actual question in the "body" of your post. But if you look at how $B$ is defined:

$$B=-5(A-I)^2$$

Which is invertible if, and only if $A-I$ is invertible(*), with the eigenvalues of $A-I$ being computed by subracting $1$ from $A$'s eigenvalues(**).

(*) The eigenvalues of $M^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $M$

(**) If $Mx=\lambda x$, then $(M-I)x=Mx-Ix = \lambda x - Ix = (\lambda-1)x$

Comment: Alternatively, we can get to "$A$ is invertible iff $0$ is not its eigenvalue" by the following reasoning: $A$ is invertible $\iff$ $A-0\cdot I$ is invertible $\iff$ $\det(A-0\cdot I)\neq 0$ $\iff$ $p_A(0)\neq 0$, where $p_A$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Comment: I know that A is invertible because 0 is not eigenvalue of it. but how can I tell if B is invertible?

Comment: @cstudent1212 Just added that part to complete the answer. AO1992 does a nice trick, but I'm not sure if that would have worked in case $B$ were indeed invertible, while this reasoning always holds

Answer (score 1):

> For matrices $A$ and $B$ of same order, if $B=f(A)$ where $f(A)$ is a polynomial then $\lambda_B=f(\lambda_A)$ holds, where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of matrix.

Since one of the $\lambda_A=1$ and $f(\lambda_A)=0$ so $\lambda_B=0$ is one of the eigenvalue of $B$.